# How to remove an XmlNode from XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, xml

I need to remove an XmlNode based on a condition. How to do it?

```
foreach (XmlNode drawNode in nodeList)
{
       //Based on a condition
       drawNode.RemoveAll();  //need to remove the entire node                      

}
```

Comment: What's the problem with that?

Comment: Need to see the original XML and what element/condition was actually attempted to be removed/used.

Answer (score 65):

This should do the trick for you:

```
for (int i = nodeList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    nodeList[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeList[i]);
}
```

If you loop using a regular for-loop, and loop over it "backwards" you can remove items as you go.

Update: here is a full example, including loading an xml file, locating nodes, deleting them and saving the file:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fileName);
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("some-xpath-query");
for (int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    nodes[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodes[i]);
}
doc.Save(fileName);
```

Comment: In this particular case it would work since the code is not removing the nodes from the XmlNodeList collection, but from the XmlDocument DOM, but in many other cases deleting items in a forward for-loop may give unexpected results (such as items not being removed). Reflex movement, I guess ;o)

Comment: This is the widely used iterative method to remove item from collections.thanks fredrik for the code wise enlightenment to all:)

Comment: Seems to not work with attribute nodes, right? (because of RemoveChild doing nothing in that case)

Comment: @IgorK: no, attributes work a bit differently. Check this code for a reworked sample for removing attributes from nodes: http://pastebin.com/gLVkKxa4

Comment: +1 for backward looping when removing nodes, works like a charm!

Comment: `doc.SelectNodes()` requires an XMLNamespaceManager.

Comment: @vapcguy There are two overloads, one that requires `XmlNamespacemanager` and one that doesn't: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlNode_SelectNodes_System_String_

Comment: @FredrikMörk Thanks - it's funny, then, because I wanted to simply use the `.SelectNodes(…)` like you did, but got this error when doing it with a Word document:  `Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function` and another person got the same error without using that `XMLNamespaceManager` overload on a separate XML construct:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202078/namespace-manager-or-xsltcontext-needed-this-query-has-a-prefix-variable-or-u/46373044?noredirect=1#comment93502387_46373044

Comment: I think that depends on your query: if the query contains namespaces, then you need to use the overload taking an `XmlNamespaceManager`, otherwise you can use the simpler version.

Answer (score 4):

You can not easily use iterators (foreach-statement) to delete your nodes.
As I see it you can do the following:

1) In your foreach-loop, save a list of all elements that should be removed. Then you loop through just those elements and remove them.

2) Use an ordinary for-loop and keep track of which is the next element to visit after you have deleted one item.

Edit: When using a for-loop do it the way Fredrik suggests, looping backwards.

Comment: Upvoting for the first answer; part 2 sounds a bit complicated the way you describe it, it's usually easier to iterate over the list in reverse order so you don't have to worry about the next index.

Comment: Why I added "..keep track of which is the next element to visit..." was because I didn't know in which way the for-loop would be implemented, if the nodes are in correct order etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to remove a node from the XML DOM, this isn't the correct way. Because an `XMLNodeList` is just a list of nodes. Rather you want to remove the node from the parent node. Like this:

```
XmlNode parentNode = // some value
XmlNode drawNode = // some value
parentNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(drawNode);
```

Comment: AFIK, XmlNode "RemoveNode" doesn't exist in C#.

Comment: Indeed, at least at 4.0. I think he meant:
   drawNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(drawNode);
It's a bit ugly but it does what I'd expect a "remove" function to do: zaps the drawNode and anything in it.

Comment: If `drawNode` is a child of `parentNode`, you don't need `.ParentNode`.  You can just simply do `parentNode.RemoveChild(drawNode);`

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the following a little simpler:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.Load(fileName); 
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("some-xpath-query"); 
while (nodes.FirstChild != null) {     
    nodes.RemoveChild(nodes.FirstChild); 
} 
doc.Save(fileName);
```

Comment: `doc.SelectNodes()` requires an XMLNamespaceManager.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me you're trying to just remove an entire XML Element...

If this is your XML...

```
<Xml1>
  <body>
    <Book>
      <Title name="Tom Sawyer" />
      <Author value="Mark Twain" />
    </Book>
    <Book>
      <Title name="A Tale of Two Cities" />
      <Author value="Charles Dickens" />
    </Book>
  </body>
</Xml1>
```

If you wanted to delete a book, you need to grab the first `<Book>` node.  You can do that with:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fileName);

XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("body");
XmlNode bodyNode = nodes[0];
XmlNode firstBook = bodyNode.ChildNodes[0];
```

Once you have the "first book" node, you can delete that from the body node using:

```
bodyNode.RemoveChild(firstBook);
```

This will automatically affect/update the XML Document variable, so `doc` will now only have:

```
<Xml1>
  <body>
    <Book>
      <Title name="A Tale of Two Cities" />
      <Author value="Charles Dickens" />
    </Book>
  </body>
</Xml1>
```

If you want to grab and delete the whole `body`, you should be able to do:

```
XmlNodeList xml1 = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Xml1");
XmlNode xmlNode = xml[0];
xmlNode.RemoveChild(bodyNode);
```

And the `doc` variable will be updated to no longer contain the `body` element, and can then be resaved to the file system:

```
doc.Save(fileName);
```

Where `fileName` is the full path to the XML Document on your computer.

Best of all, we aren't using `doc.SelectNodes()`, so we don't need to worry about using an `XMLNamespaceManager`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    XmlNodeList xnodeContact = xmldocContact.GetElementsByTagName("contact");
          foreach (ListViewItem item in listViewContacts.Items)
            {
                if (item.Checked)
                {
                    if (item.Index >= 0)
                        xnodeContact[0].ParentNode.RemoveChild(xnodeContact[0]);
                        listViewContacts.Items.Remove(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            xmldocContact.Save(appdataPath + "\\WhatAppcontactList.xml");
            Invalidate();
```