# How to delete node from XML file using C#

Tags: c#, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove an XmlNode from XmlNodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875136/how-to-remove-an-xmlnode-from-xmlnodelist)

Hi, How can i delete a set of nodes from an XML file.? 
Here is a code snippet.

```
string path = @"C:\Documents and Settings\e454935\Desktop\NUnitSettings.xml";
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
System.Xml.XmlDocument xmldoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(fs);
fs.Close();
xmldoc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(xmldoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[1]);
FileStream WRITER = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
xmldoc.Save(WRITER);
WRITER.Close();
```

I tried the following code simply to delete a node and got
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at

```
xmldoc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(xmldoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[1]);
```

Here is a sample XML file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Xml1>
  <Settings>
    <Setting name="DisplayFormat" value="Full" />
    <Setting name="File1" value="a" />
    <Setting name="File1" value="b" />
    <Setting name="File1" value="c" />
    <Setting name="File1" value="d" />
  </Settings>
</Xml1>
```

Actually from this file i want to delete the **Four File1 nodes** which has the values "a,b,c,d" and then i want to **add a node**,

```
<Setting name="File1" value="e" />
```

How can i do this.?

Comment: This has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875136 already, and probably two dozen times in other questions. Voted to close as a dupe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may be easier to use XPath to locate the nodes that you wish to delete. [This stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875136/how-to-remove-an-xmlnode-from-xmlnodelist/) might give you some ideas.

In your case you will find the four nodes that you want using this expression:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fileName);
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//Setting[@name='File1']");
```

Answer (score 31):

You can use [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to do this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
var q = from node in doc.Descendants("Setting")
        let attr = node.Attribute("name")
        where attr != null && attr.Value == "File1"
        select node;
q.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
doc.Save("output.xml");
```

Answer (score 14):

Deleting nodes from XML

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(path);
            XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//Setting[@name='File1']");
            for (int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                nodes[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodes[i]);
            }
            doc.Save(path);
```

Adding attribute to Nodes in XML

```
    XmlDocument originalXml = new XmlDocument();
    originalXml.Load(path);
    XmlNode menu = originalXml.SelectSingleNode("//Settings");
    XmlNode newSub = originalXml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Setting", null);
    XmlAttribute xa = originalXml.CreateAttribute("name");
    xa.Value = "qwerty";
    XmlAttribute xb = originalXml.CreateAttribute("value");
    xb.Value = "555";
    newSub.Attributes.Append(xa);
    newSub.Attributes.Append(xb);
    menu.AppendChild(newSub);
    originalXml.Save(path);
```

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, but +1 from me.  That node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node) is a handy line of code to remember.

Answer (score 3):

`DocumentElement` is the root node of the document so `childNodes[1]` doesn't exist in that document. `childNodes[0]` would be the <Settings> node

Comment: +1 for explaining where the error lies.