# How to delete XML nodes based on an internal value comparison

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<tu>
    <tuv xml:lang="EN">
        <seg>XXX</seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv xml:lang="FR">
        <seg>YYY</seg>
    </tuv>
</tu>
<tu>
    <tuv xml:lang="EN">
        <seg>XXX</seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv xml:lang="FR">
        <seg>YYY</seg>
    </tuv>
</tu>
...
```

And I would like to delete the node `<tu>` when `<seg>XXX</seg>` is equal to `<seg>YYY</seg>` from a C# application. I have tried with linq and in some other ways, but I wasn't able to compare those internal valuea and then delete the parent node if necessary.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I have tried linq code found in other similar questions here (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919645/how-to-delete-node-from-xml-file-using-c/919687#919687). The problem I have is that all samples show how to query, select and delete, but I can't find anything that also compares internal values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your XML is invalid so I added a `<root>` node - then this worked for me:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

var nodesWithMatchingElements = doc.Root.Elements("tu")
                                   .GroupBy(e => e)
                                   .Select(g => new 
                                    { 
                                       Element = g.Key, 
                                       Count = g.Descendants("seg").Select(x => x.Value).Distinct().Count() 
                                    })
                                   .Where(x => x.Count == 1);

foreach (var node in nodesWithMatchingElements)
    node.Element.Remove();
```