# Delete outer xml node without deleting inner xml

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, xmlnode

This is my xml:

```
<application name="Test Tables">
<test>
  <xs:schema id="test" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">   
  </xs:schema> 
</test>
</application>
```

How can I delete the `<application>` node without deleting the `<test>` node ?

Comment: Waiting in suspense for what you want to delete... ;)

Comment: Lol Am assuming its the "test " tag you don't want to delete.  i think you have to put them as code - on a new line with a four space indent, otherwise they're stripped.

Comment: (note that whenever you want to use a `<`, it **must** be code-formatted: use the `{}` icon, or encase in backticks, or indent by four characters)

Comment: @JacobusR No a stupid student did: String.Append("<application...)... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so probably not my best answer, but hoping either this fits your need, or gives you a a good starting point.  Firstly, I'm assuming that you're using C#.  So, the way I did this, was to use the node you want to remove and select its child nodes and use them to create a new XDocument.  There could be a neater way using Linq to achieve this, but I'm damned if I can see it!  Anyway, hope this helps :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@".\Test1.xml");

var q = (from node in doc.Descendants("application")
        let attr = node.Attribute("name")
        where attr != null && attr.Value == "Test Tables"
        select node.DescendantNodes()).Single();

var doc2 =  XDocument.Parse(q.First().ToString());
```

I used this SO post as my guide : [How to delete node from XML file using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919645/how-to-delete-node-from-xml-file-using-c-sharp)

Happy coding,
Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: ok you just featch the "inner" Node and put it into a new xml document. Well... ok at least it should work ;-)

Comment: That's it basically - yeah! :)  Not quite as smarty as removing the the outer node.  Annoying me, cos I'm sure there's a better way!! But this should server your purposes hopefully!

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT you could do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="application">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="test"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice. Although, the Linq-to-XML tag was included by the OP. I've included a rather more crude solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's this;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string doc = @"
                    <application name=""Test Tables"">
                    <test>
                      <xs:schema id=""test"" xmlns="""" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""                         xmlns:msdata=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"">   
                      </xs:schema> 
                    </test>
                    </application>
                    ";
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(doc);
        Console.Write(xDoc.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();

        string descendants = xDoc.Descendants("application").DescendantNodes().First().ToString();
        xDoc = XDocument.Parse(descendants);
        Console.Write(xDoc.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Although I'm a little curious as to why you would want to do this...