# Remove Tag from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How can I remove the **workbookProtection** tag?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<workbook xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="x15" xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main">
  <fileVersion appName="xl" lastEdited="6" lowestEdited="6" rupBuild="14420" />
  <workbookPr filterPrivacy="1" codeName="ThisWorkbook" defaultThemeVersion="164011" />
  <workbookProtection workbookAlgorithmName="SHA-512" workbookHashValue="MI+PN5CyUQ3XO6V0pjh3peL3nUtsQcVWhtDfT6PQjyrHvEBu9Hk+dzFJxHm3V5vxGgtgMk1eLpi62pzDLJ9Y4w==" workbookSaltValue="yhbUOo6A+kVhRScY5lXa3g==" workbookSpinCount="100000" lockStructure="1" />
  <bookViews>
    <workbookView xWindow="-120" yWindow="-120" windowWidth="21840" windowHeight="13140" tabRatio="658" />
  </bookViews>
 ...
</workbook>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete node from XML file using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919645/how-to-delete-node-from-xml-file-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @tnw no i tested but not worked

Comment: Show your code so far, then, and tell us what specific problem you're running into.

Comment: @tnw XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
            var q = from node in doc.Descendants("workbookProtection")
                select node;
            q.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
            doc.Save("output.xml");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the Namespace when you try to get the `workbookProtection`, by using **Linq to Xml** :

1 - Declare the namespace :

```
XNamespace xn = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";
```

2 - Remove the **workbookProtection**

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
var q = from node in doc.Descendants(xn + "workbookProtection")
        select node;
q.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
```

For Test :

```
string xml = @"
<workbook xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"" xmlns:r=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"" xmlns:mc=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"" mc:Ignorable=""x15"" xmlns:x15=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main"">
  <fileVersion appName=""xl"" lastEdited=""6"" lowestEdited=""6"" rupBuild=""14420"" />
  <workbookPr filterPrivacy=""1"" codeName=""ThisWorkbook"" defaultThemeVersion=""164011"" />
  <workbookProtection workbookAlgorithmName=""SHA-512"" workbookHashValue=""MI+PN5CyUQ3XO6V0pjh3peL3nUtsQcVWhtDfT6PQjyrHvEBu9Hk+dzFJxHm3V5vxGgtgMk1eLpi62pzDLJ9Y4w=="" workbookSaltValue=""yhbUOo6A+kVhRScY5lXa3g=="" workbookSpinCount=""100000"" lockStructure=""1"" />
  <bookViews>
    <workbookView xWindow=""-120"" yWindow=""-120"" windowWidth=""21840"" windowHeight=""13140"" tabRatio=""658"" />
  </bookViews>
</workbook>";

XNamespace xn = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var q = from node in doc.Descendants(xn + "workbookProtection")
        select node;
q.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());

Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

**Result**:

```
<workbook xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmln
s:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:
mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="x
15" xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main">
  <fileVersion appName="xl" lastEdited="6" lowestEdited="6" rupBuild="14420" />
  <workbookPr filterPrivacy="1" codeName="ThisWorkbook" defaultThemeVersion="164
011" />
  <bookViews>
    <workbookView xWindow="-120" yWindow="-120" windowWidth="21840" windowHeight
="13140" tabRatio="658" />
  </bookViews>
</workbook>
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: you're welcome!, try just `doc.Descendants(xn + "workbookProtection").Remove();` it's wrok too.