# Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

I am trying to call `SelectNode` from `XmlDocument` class and trouble due to this error:

> Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

My code:

```
   public void Add(ref XmlDocument xmlFormat, String strName)
   {
        XmlDocument dom;
        XSLTemplate xsl = null;
        String strPath = "";
        XmlNodeList nl;
        XmlAttribute na;
        int n;

        nl = (XmlNodeList)xmlFormat.SelectNodes("//xsl:import/@href",nsm);
    }
```

and xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="stylesheets/r_adresetiket.xsl" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="retouradres">
            <xsl:with-param name="_retouradres" select="data/adresetiket/_retouradres" />
            <xsl:with-param name="minofdir" select="data/adresetiket/afzendgegevens/afzendgegevens" />
            <xsl:with-param name="checked" select="data/adresetiket/LB" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202078/namespace-manager-or-xsltcontext-needed-this-query-has-a-prefix-variable-or-u/46373044?noredirect=1#comment93502508_46373044

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You have to add `xsl` namespace to `XmlNamespaceManager`:

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(...);
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");

var nl = document.SelectNodes("//xsl:import/@href", nsmgr);
```

Answer (score 32):

The document can be traversed by `GetElementsByTagName` and it doesn't necessarily need using `XmlNamespaceManager`:

```
var nodes = document.GetElementsByTagName("xsl:import");
var href =  nodes[0].Attributes["href"];
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AqQ9So)

Comment: how can you get nested elements given the path lets say  "xsl1:elem1/xsl2:elem2" thsi doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 6):

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(rawData);

var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("cbc", "urn:xxx"); //for example
nsmgr.AddNamespace("cac", "urn:yyy");            

XmlElement xmlElem = document.DocumentElement;
var node = xmlElem.SelectSingleNode("cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID[@schemeID='VKN']/text()", nsmgr);
var nodeText = node.InnerText;
```

[image]

All namespaces that will be used in XML should be added.
Then you can access the values of the relevant nodes using `xpath`.