# When calling format-number XPath function, I receive error: "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed."

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath, xelement

I am trying to evaluate an XPath expression which contains the function [`format-number`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256225(v=vs.110).aspx) within the C# method [`XPathEvaluate(XNode, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341675(v=vs.110).aspx). A simplified reproduction is as follows:

```
// In this example, the XML is not actually used; written purely to demonstrate the issue
XElement test =  new XElement("test", 12);
object output = test.XPathEvaluate("format-number(2, \"00\")");
```

When this runs, the following exception is thrown:

> **System.Xml.XPath.XPathException**: 'Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.'

I have tried to add the XSLT namespace to an `XmlNamespaceManager` which is then provided to the `XPathEvaluate` function, as suggested by the exception message and in an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13512499/5513562), but that also did not work:

```
var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
manager.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");
test.XPathEvaluate("format-number(2, \"00\")", manager);
```

How can I call the `format-number` function within an XPath statement?

Comment: Microsoft only offers XSLT and XPath 1 support where `format-number` is an XSLT only function not exposed to XPath. In actual versions of XPath https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-format-number the function is also available to XPath so if you use a third party library like Saxon 9 you can use XPath 3 and `format-number`, although I don't think they offer that for the LINQ to XML object model with `XElement`, only for the DOM `XmlElement`.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I was able to use `format-number` in XSLT 1.0 invoked from a .NET application, so assumed it should work via the C# also.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, your English is superb but you have fallen into a translation trap: "Aktuell" does not translate into "Actual". You mean "current versions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `format-number` function is not supported by MS XPath. It doesn't contain a lot of functions of XSLT. You can find all supporting functions in picture from post [here](http://www.devowl.net/2018/03/xpathnavigator-xpath-if-else-string-format-current-functions.html).

But you can have to create your own function here. In article from above you can found my 3 function examples (if-else, format and current).

Sorry, my native language is Russian, but there is translation button. So, you need only take a look on the 1st image and check example code from the first [download](https://github.com/devowl/xpathfunctions) link. I hope you can copy code and implement your needed functionality for `format-number`.