# How To User XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform independent of SignedXml class

Tags: c#, xml, xml-signature, xslt

All the [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byw7ae3k%28v=vs.71%29) on the internet shows the usage of the XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform class as a part of the SignedXml class.

I would like to use this class by itself. Just give it a nodeList get the result without the signature node.

```
XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform envSigTrans = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
envSigTrans.LoadInput(xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//*"));
XmlNodeList nodeList = (XmlNodeList)envSigTrans.GetOutput(typeof(XmlNodeList));
```

But the output nodeList still contains the ds:Signature node I would like to get rid of.

What is the correct way of doing this? Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Just came into the same issue myself. Turns out that if you use XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform "as is" you will always get all nodes back. I have tracked down XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform in the reflector and it will only remove the signature if it has a value in _signaturePosition. This is a private API though which only MS uses intertnally (by SignedInfo) so by large XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform is not usefull as a user. The good news is that you can set it manually via private reflection. If your Xml has only one signature element in it the value should always be one.

```
    var transform = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform(false);
    transform.LoadInput(xmldoc);        
    FieldInfo field = transform.GetType().GetField("_signaturePosition", 
                     BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                     BindingFlags.Instance);
    field.SetValue(transform, 1);                
    var res = (XmlDocument)t.GetOutput();
    var str = res.OuterXml;
```

Answer (score 0):

> "But the output nodeList still contains the ds:Signature node I would like to get rid of."

If you just want to get rid of the  element, why don't you just remove it from the list?

Have a look at this:

[How to remove an XmlNode from XmlNodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875136/how-to-remove-an-xmlnode-from-xmlnodelist)