# How to remove particular item from XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I want to write a method to remove given index from the nodelist. is there any way to do it?

If i try this below code it removes the xml, but still the empty node exists, the count of the xmlnodelist is same as before remove.

```
public static void removeItem(XmlNodeList nodes, int index)
{
   nodes.Item(i).RemoveAll();
}
```

Can anyone help me how to remove the particular item by index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove an XmlNode from XmlNodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875136/how-to-remove-an-xmlnode-from-xmlnodelist)

Answer (score 0):

I'm little confused about the variable `i` in your code. Anyway, if you have to remove a node from the `XmlNodeList`, you have to remove the node from its parentNode. so the method can be rewritten as like the following:

```
public static void removeItem(XmlNodeList nodes, int index)
{
   nodes[index].ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodes[index])
}
```

Comment: Actually i tried this solution , but it throws below exception , thats why i want to try some other option     <af:exception message="The xpath query is too complex." type="System.Xml.XPath.XPathException" />                                                                   where ProcessNode is called exactly 1025 times. You can find the limit specified on line 392 and the operation on line 396 of the code specified here:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.xml/System/Xml/XPath/Internal/QueryBuilder.cs